# Trimming down Stackable Header

Tags: gpio

As mentioned in [my previous post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88590/risk-of-damage-soldering-directly-to-gpio), I'm intending to solder some HATs directly to the Pi. However, I find the pins on the default header too short, so I need to replace them with longer ones.

I have [this Stackable Header from Adafruit with Extra Long pins](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1979), but the female part of the header gives it too much height so I would like to remove it. As is apparent from the image, the male headers are somehow attached to the female header and probably can be removed. Eventually, I want to end up with [something like this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2822) which, unfortunately is unavailable where I live.

Is the top part soldered into the bottom part? Is there a safe way to separate the them?

Comment: Do you plan to extract the original header and put a new one?

Answer (score 0):

"Cutting" header pins is a bad idea. Look at the end very closely.
Unless you 
plug it in and leave it in 
or remove any burrs from the tip 
you are asking for trouble. 
2x20 headers are tricky to plug in, just imagine plugging it in with "squared" heads,

Answer (score 0):

These are generic parts, sold by Adafruit as a hobby distributor. These parts are made and sold all over the world with  thousands of options. Keywords:

- Male Pin Header
- 40 positions
- 2 Rows
- 0.1" Pitch
- Unshrouded
- Through Hole Mounting

These parts are available to order,  in nearly every size imaginable, from places that are happy to deliver anywhere in the world like Digikey, Mouser, and Newark.

As a specific example.

[Digikey paramateric search](https://www.digikey.com/short/pqc0z1) for 40 pin (2x20) 0.1" Pitch Male Pin Unshrouded headers has about 400 options with pin lengths from 2mm to 32mm